# ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: mysql, hibernate, docker

My web application run well on localhost.but after changing localhost to XX.X.XX.X i.e. ip of docker in hibernate.properties i get following error

**AbandonedObjectPool is used

(org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@66d1439c)

LogAbandoned: true

RemoveAbandoned: true

RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 90**

after entering XX.X.XX.X:1112/student the login page or home page comes but after login i get following error in command prompt (from where i started tomcat)

**57521 [http-apr-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

57522 [http-apr-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory**

Command use to start the tomcat server is **docker run -it --rm -p 7008:8080 -v //d/docker_tomcat/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml:ro -v //d/docker_tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:rw tomcat:7.0**

i am sure there is no problem in above command.

here is my hibernate.properties file:-

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=root
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://<ip of docker>:3306/studentdb?autoreconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
show_sql=false
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false
hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow=true
hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn=false
hibernate.dbcp.maxWait=2000
hibernate.dbcp.testWhileIdle=true
hibernate.dbcp.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
hibernate.dbcp.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000
hibernate.dbcp.numTestsPerEvictionRun=5
hibernate.dbcp.removeAbandoned=true
hibernate.dbcp.removeAbandonedTimeout=90
hibernate.dbcp.logAbandoned=true
```

Answer (score 0):

i have change hibernate.connection.url property with instead of ip address of docker i use the ip address of mysql container.
you can get ip address of mysql container using following command:-

> `**docker inspect some-mysql**`  here some-mysql is container name (you can
>   get container name by `docker ps` command)